# How to handle the canceled request inside forloop in Angular.?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 5+ pages in my App. I have the following method on header component.

The aim is, I need to show the status in the header if the user clicks the particular button. If I make a minimal or slow navigation between pages below code works fine. But if I navigate pages very frequently, the request getting canceled, because in some other pages I am calling the different set of API's.

```
async geneStatus() {
    for (const x of Object.keys(this.gene)) {
    const operationId = this.gene[x]['name'];
    let operArr;
    try {
        operArr = await this.fetchEachStatus(name);
    } catch (err) {
        continue;
    }
    if (operArr[0] && operArr[0] === 'error') {
        continue;
    }
 // Doing my logics
}


fetchEachStatus(geneId): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.apiDataService.get(this.geneUrl+ '/' + geneId).subscribe(
        (res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(res);
        }, 500);
        }, err => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(['error']);
        }, 500);
        });
    });
}
```

Here the problem is if any one of the API gets cancelled the for loop is not iterating for the next elements. I need to iterate the loop if one API is get cancelled. How can I fix this issue? I am not sure where I am making the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues. I think the conversion to observable to promise is not only unnecessary, but counter-productive. Using the observables directly would enable you to use RxJS functions and operators. We can use the `forkJoin` function to make multiple simultaneous requests and `catchError` operator to mitigate the effects of potential errors.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

geneStatus() {
  forkJoin(Object.keys(this.gene).map(gene => this.fetchEachStatus(gene['name']))).subscribe(
    res => {
      // res[0] - `{ success: true | false, geneId: geneId }` from `this.apiDataService.get(this.geneUrl + '/' + this.gene[0]['name'])`
      // res[1] - `{ success: true | false, geneId: geneId }` from `this.apiDataService.get(this.geneUrl + '/' + this.gene[1]['name'])`
      ...

      const passedGeneIds = res.filter(item => item.success).map(item => item.geneId);
      // passedGeneIds = [`geneId`, `geneId`, ...] - list of passed gene IDs

      const failedGeneIds = res.filter(item => !item.success).map(item => item.geneId);
      // failedGeneIds = [`geneId`, `geneId`, ...] - list of failed gene IDs

      // some other logic
    },
    error => {
      // essentially will never be hit since all the errors return a response instead
    }
  );
}

fetchEachStatus(geneId): Observable<any> {
  return this.apiDataService.get(this.geneUrl + '/' + geneId).pipe(
    map(_ => ({ sucess: true, geneId: geneId })),                  // <-- map to return the `geneId`
    catchError(error => of({ sucess: false, geneId: geneId }))     // <-- retun an observble from `catchError`
  );
}
```

Now you need to remember that *each time* a button is clicked multiple simultaeneous requests are triggered. One solution to overcome this issue is to cancel all current requests before triggering a new set of request. For that you could bind the buttons to emit a central observable and trigger the requests using `switchMap` operator piped to that observable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. could you please tell me how to use `gene['name']` inside the subscribe.?

Comment: @mkHun: You could use RxJS `map` operator to return the `geneId`s from the request. However since the requests are parallel, you might not have a context of which requests passed and which failed. So I am returning an object with a boolean property `success` that denotes if the HTTP request has been successful.